# How do I use google fonts on defining a theme in flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts, google-fonts

I am new to flutter.

I installed [this](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) library to be able to use google fonts.

Now I need to do it in the theme data definition, and tried like this but it's not allowed

```
ThemeData appTheme() {
  return ThemeData(
    ...
    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.openSans(),
  );
}
```

How do I do this? Thank you very much

Comment: `fontFamily` expects a `String`. Use `GoogleFonts.openSans().fontFamily`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Riwen, if you want to add it as answer I can accept it then

Comment: Reposted my comment as an actual answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Reposting my comment: `fontFamily` expects a `String`. Use `GoogleFonts.openSans().fontFamily`.

Answer (score 16):

Paste the code below in your theme file, and add it to your ThemeData(textTheme: textTheme)

```
final TextTheme textTheme = TextTheme(
  headline1: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 97, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, letterSpacing: -1.5),
  headline2: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 61, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, letterSpacing: -0.5),
  headline3: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: 48, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  headline4: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 34, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, letterSpacing: 0.25),
  headline5: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
  headline6: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, letterSpacing: 0.15),
  subtitle1: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, letterSpacing: 0.15),
  subtitle2: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, letterSpacing: 0.1),
  bodyText1: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, letterSpacing: 0.5),
  bodyText2: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, letterSpacing: 0.25),
  button: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, letterSpacing: 1.25),
  caption: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, letterSpacing: 0.4),
  overline: GoogleFonts.roboto(
      fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, letterSpacing: 1.5),
);
```

This video explains very well how to use themes and fonts in flutter https://youtu.be/stoJpMeS5aY?t=640

Comment: is the website to get the code she is showing in the video available yet?

Comment: Is available, you can get the code for flutter, web and android xml. https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale

Comment: Thank you. I had to give the accepted answer to Riwen because it was exactly what I asked

Comment: This is the way if you are using Google Font and want to adjust the fontsizes.

Comment: There's no need to do this 1 by 1 though, just use the method to get the entire TextTheme for the font you're using. For example: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(), or GoogleFonts.cinzelDecorativeTextTheme()

Answer (score 10):

In `main.dart` file add

```
 fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
```

[image]

Comment: It's better to use codeblocks in your response - add code with 3 backticks and the name of the language to open the code block and 3 backticks to close the codeblock like ``` ... or use the `{}` button in the rich text editor - you can add comments to the code to highlight part of it

Answer (score 1):

```
return MaterialApp( theme:ThemeData(textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme()));
```

Comment: import google_fonts package first

Answer (score 0):

fontFamily expects a String. Use `GoogleFonts.openSans().fontFamily`

or follow  [https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts](https://Google%20fonts) documentation