# How to use GoogleFonts as default fonts in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using GoogleFonts api in my flutter app but right now I am setting the fontStyle for every text manually to GoogleFonts.roberto but I want to set that as default in ThemeData in main.dart. But the fontFamily: GoogleFonts.roberto throws an error saying expected an string value so how can I achive that?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64271758/10795937

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I found a way around I'm built a TextStyle function in my widgets file with parameters for fontSize, Color and other properties and I'm calling that for every text. That's working but do you think that's adding boilerplate code and should I use your way? Your thoughts on this.

Comment: Take a look at the video that is in the answer, he can take your doubts about it. That way you can define the basis for all your textStyle. If you need to change a property somewhere, you can use copyWith. style: Theme.of (context) .textTheme.headline1.copyWith (color: Colors.white).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use it like this to make or modify an entire text theme to use the "Roboto" font as mentioned in their [official document](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts):

```
  MaterialApp(
     theme:ThemeData(
       textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(
           Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
  );
```

Comment: The problem is my App is not reacting to Dark or Light Theme with Google Fonts, when switching theme