# How can I Allow a user to change font in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wanting to allow my users to have more customization in the UI of our app. Currently, our app is set up using ThemeData and Google Fonts.

I've implemented a simple dropdown to allow a user to select a font. How can I then take that selected font and change all fonts globally?

Main road block I'm finding it that I only want to change the font in TextStyle and not fontWeight / fontSize etc.  I can save the user's selection via shared preferences or to the users collection on Firebase, but then how can I change .roboto to the selected choice.

Example of how I currently use Google Fonts (my current font is Roboto)

```
AutoSizeText(
                                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.newNote,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                ),
```

Let me know if you need more explenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can implemnent it similar to the `themeMode` setting in the [new Flutter app skeleton](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/skeleton/lib/src/app.dart.tmpl). Something like this, only changing `fontFamily` as an example:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
    required this.settingsController,
  });

  final SettingsController settingsController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The AnimatedBuilder Widget listens to the SettingsController for changes.
    // Whenever the user updates their settings, the MaterialApp is rebuilt.    
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: settingsController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        final themeData = ThemeData(
            fontFamily: settingsController.fontFamily,  // for example  GoogleFonts.roboto().fontFamily
          );
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: themeData,
          // ...
```

The [SettingsController class](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/skeleton/lib/src/settings/settings_controller.dart.tmpl) should implement `ChangeNotifier` and call `notifyListeners()` when the user changes font.

Se this post on how to use Roboto in a TextTheme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64271758/20444